# How to measure laptop current draw?

Tags: laptop, battery, power

I'm interested in quantifying how much my laptop costs to run (as I know the kWh cost). However, I need to know the wattage of my laptop in standby or usage mode.

Is there some reliable software that can read current draw?

I can see that on the transformer for the laptop, it reads 2.25A at 20V. However, I doubt that if I have my computer idling, it will be drawing 2.25A (am I correct in assuming that 2.25A is the max amperage this transformer can provide?).

One way that I thought of, was to charge the battery to 100%, then let it run down to 75% and measure the time taken whilst idling or when running some specific software. Since we know the capacity of the laptop (in Ah), we should be able to calculate the power usage (multiply by battery voltage - can be measured from HWMonitor). This is a bit tedious - any nice software solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Since the power usage varies *greatly* by battery state (CPU may throttle immediately on battery, and throttle further as charge drops), CPU load, power supply reactance (which factors in Volt-Ampere to Watt calculation) and other parameters, unless you actually *measure* the Watt-hour usage with an integrating meter over sufficient time to include sleep, gaming, internet usage, etc., any estimate will be *way* off.
Further, any possible *software* measurement would not include efficiency losses in the power supply.

There are Watt-hour meters available for [~US$17](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XH73LJB) and [~US$21](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VPTN8FZ), as well as others that might meet your needs, if you want to spend that.